# Creating Game Boundaries and Barriers in Flash CS6 AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, flash-cs6

I'm new to AS3 and I'm trying to make a little game for a Flash class.  I have the scene set up so my character is on the scene, and I just need it so whenever he walks he's not running off the screen or running on top of objects that he should just stop at.  So I need him to stop when he hits the edges, and stop when he hits certain objects, which are all on separate layers and are individual Movie Clips.  Here's the code which I have so far.

```
stop();

hero.gotoAndStop('still');

var Key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

function onenter(e:Event):void {
    if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
       hero.x+=5;
       hero.scaleX=.7;
       hero.gotoAndStop('walking');
       }else if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
       hero.x-=5;
       hero.scaleX=-.7;
       hero.gotoAndStop('walking');
       }else if(Key.isDown(Key.UP)){
       hero.y-=5;
       hero.gotoAndStop('walking');
       }else if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)){
       hero.y+=5;
       hero.gotoAndStop('walking');
       }else{
           hero.gotoAndStop('still');
       }
}
if(hero.x > rightBound){
  GameScene.x += rightBound - player.x;
  hero.x = rightBound;
}
```

Any help?  The main hero's name is "hero" and the scene it's on is called "GameScene".  Also, I guess this is related, but how would I get the scene to change when the hero hits a certain object?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

add another condition to the if statements that only allows the code to run if the player's x/y is lower/higher than a specific value.

example:
     if(Key.isDown(Key.UP)&&hero.y<300)//the barrier is at y 300